# DB2 sql query to a Pandas DataFrame from my Mac

Tags: python, macos, pandas, db2

I have a need to access data that resides in a remote db2 database via a sql statement and convert it to a Pandas DataFrame. All from my Mac.  I looked at using Pandas' [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) with the [ibm_db_sa](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa) adapter, but it looks like the prerequisite client side software is not supported on the Mac

I came up with an jdbc option, which I'm posting, but I'm curious to know if anyone else has any ideas

Comment: There is an official [IBM Data Server Driver package](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217) for macOS that should allow you to build ibm_db.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde  Thanks!  I'll check it out

Comment: @IanBjorhovde Thanks for the advice.  I'm all set up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @IanBjorhovde commented on my question I investigated another solution that allows me to use sqlalchemy and pandas' read_sql()

Here are the steps I took. Note: I got this working on OSX Yosemite (10.10.4) for python 3.4 and 3.5

1) Download IBM DB2 Express-C (no-cost community edition of DB2)

https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pick.do?source=swg-db2expressc&S_TACT=000000VR&lang=en_US&S_OFF_CD=10000761

2) After navigating to the unzipped dir

```
sudo ./db2_install
```

I accepted the default location of /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1

3) Install [ibm_db](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/ibm_db_on_MAC_OS_Hints_and_Tips?lang=en) and ibm_db_sa

```
pip install ibm_db
```

I built ibm_db_sa from [source](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa) because the pip installed failed

```
python setup.py install
```

That should do it.  You might get an error like 'Reason: image not found' when you try to connect to your db so read [this](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/tree/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db#issues-with-mac-os-x) for the fix.  Note: might require a reboot

Example usage:

```
import ibm_db_sa
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine

eng = create_engine('ibm_db_sa://<user_name>:<pwd>@<host>:5032/<db name>')
sql = 'SELECT name FROM table_name FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY'
df = pd.read_sql(sql, eng)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using jdbc, the pip installable [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) and the appropriate db jar file

Note: this could be used for other jdbc/[jaydebeapi compliant databases](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi#supported-databases) like Oracle, MS Sql Server, etc

```
import jaydebeapi
import pandas as pd

def read_jdbc(sql, jclassname, driver_args, jars=None, libs=None):
    '''
    Reads jdbc compliant data sources and returns a Pandas DataFrame

    uses jaydebeapi.connect and doc strings :-)
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/

    :param sql: select statement
    :param jclassname: Full qualified Java class name of the JDBC driver. 
        e.g. org.postgresql.Driver or com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver 
    :param driver_args: Argument or sequence of arguments to be passed to the
       Java DriverManager.getConnection method. Usually the
       database URL. See
       http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html
       for more details
    :param jars: Jar filename or sequence of filenames for the JDBC driver
    :param libs: Dll/so filenames or sequence of dlls/sos used as 
       shared library by the JDBC driver
    :return: Pandas DataFrame
    '''

    try:
        conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname, driver_args, jars, libs)
    except jaydebeapi.DatabaseError as de:
        raise

    try:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(sql)

        columns = [desc[0] for desc in curs.description] #getting column headers

        #convert the list of tuples from fetchall() to a df
        return pd.DataFrame(curs.fetchall(), columns=columns) 

    except jaydebeapi.DatabaseError as de:
        raise

    finally:
        curs.close()
        conn.close()
```

Some examples

```
#DB2
conn = 'jdbc:db2://<host>:5032/<db>:currentSchema=<schema>;'
class_name = 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'

sql = 'SELECT name FROM table_name FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY'

df = read_jdbc(sql, class_name, [conn, 'myname', 'mypwd'])

#PostgreSQL        
conn = 'jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/<db>?currentSchema=<schema>'
class_name = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
jar = '/path/to/jar/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar'

sql = 'SELECT name FROM table_name LIMIT 5'

df = read_jdbc(sql, class_name, [conn, 'myname', 'mypwd'], jars=jar)
```

Comment: is JayDeBeApi still supported/maintained?  As of Apr 2020, the last release on pypi was on Mar 2017

Comment: I'm not sure.  I got the impression that it never had an active support community

Answer (score 1):

I got a simpler answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805547/914967 where it uses pip module `ibm_db` only:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd

conn_handle = ibm_db.connect('DATABASE={};HOSTNAME={};PORT={};PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={};PWD={};'.format(db_name, hostname, port_number, user, password), '', '')

conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn_handle)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

Comment: Very nice!  ODBC driver installation is still required I'm guessing?

Comment: @BobHaffner, yes IDBC driver installation it is required!

Answer (score 0):

Bob, you should check out ibmdbpy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibmdbpy). It is a pandas data frame style API to DB2 and dashDB tables. It supports both underlying DB2 client drivers, ODBC and JDBC.

So as prerequisites you need to set up the DB2 client driver package for Mac that you can find here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217

Comment: Thanks, Torsten, I will!